# Running applications from terminal

Tags: command-line

How can i run applications from terminal in ubuntu desktop ? for example if i want to run CODE::BLOCKS IDE from terminal , is there any command to do so?

Answer (score 3):

It is usually possible to run every application from terminal. There are a number to ways in which you can try to determine the program name to type in the terminal.

For example you can run the GUI application from the menu and then type the following in the terminal.

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

Once you click on the GUI app, xprop will tell you the application name that can then be typed in the terminal.

As for codeblocks I just ran it from the terminal using the following command.

```
codeblocks
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code::Blocks_command_line_arguments), to run Code :: Blocks in terminal type:

`codeblocks --no-splash-screen --debug-log`